# How to get the current output dB values of background music to display a sound level meter in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio

Is there an easy way to read current dB sound level values of what iOS it putting out to the speakers / or from background music that is playing?

Comment: i'm looking for it as well

Answer (score 0):

No.  An app can not get the audio output levels for the sound that any other app, for instance a background music player, is currently playing.

Comment: barring the headphone case, you could record the speaker output with a non exclusive audio session category. it's probably too awful to contemplate for a level meter, but it makes sense in some contexts, e.g. shazam, which can identify music playing from other apps running on the same device.