# Meter audio level from Embedded YouTube video that plays inline in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, youtube, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to find a way to get the average power level for a channel, that comes out from the audio played in the embedded video. I'm using YouTube's iOS helper library for embedding the video https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

A lot of the answers I've found in StackOverflow refer to AVAudioPlayer, but that's not my case. I also looked in the docs of AudioKit framework to find something that can give the output level of the current audio, but I couldn't find anything related, maybe I missed something over there. I also looked in EZAudio framework even tough it's deprecated, and I also couldn't find something that relates to my case.

My direction of thinking was to find a way to get the actual level that's coming out from the device, but I found one answer in SO that's saying this is not allowed in iOS, although he didn't mention any source for this statement.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12664340/4711172

So, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The iOS security sandbox locks apps out of seeing the devices or any other app's internal audio output (unless explicitly shared, e.g. inter-app audio, etc.)  Likely originally to prevent capturing samples of DRM'd music and recording phone calls.

Comment: @hotpaw2 thanks for your reply, I had a feeling this is something impossible, just didn't get a reasonable answer for it, like yours.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS security sandbox blocks apps from seeing the device's digital audio output stream, or any other app's internal audio output (unless explicitly shared, e.g. inter-app audio, etc.) (when using Apple App store permitted public APIs.)

(Just a guess, but this was possibly and originally implemented in iOS to prevent apps from capturing samples of DRM'd music and/or recording phone call conversations.)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit off/weird, but just in case - 
Have you considered closing a loop? Meaning - record the incoming audio using 'AVAudio​Recorder' and get the audio levels from there?.

See Apple's documentation for AVAudioRecorder (in the overview they're specifying: *"Obtain input audio-level data that you can use to provide level metering"*)
[AVAudioRecorder documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder)

Comment: Hi Kobi thanks for your reply. I did considier this kind of workaround, but it is not directly what I need, if you read further they say that the "input audio-level" is what comes from the phone's microphone or a microphone from an headset. I thought about recording from the mic the actual audio that comes from the device, but then what happens if the user uses headphones? Anyways for fun I will try it.

Comment: Ah.. you're right. Somehow I've missed the 'microphone/headset' thing. Sorry for not being very helpful. 
I was trying to look around for this, but the closest I got was to download the actual data (audio or audio+video) and then access/process the audio data but I'm guessing you need it to be real-time so that's not relevant either.